# how to select a particular field using a jquery

Tags: php, jquery

my code is

```
<div id="fields">
<form id="question-form">  <input type="hidden" name="question-main" value="<?php echo mysql_prep($_GET['ques']);?>" /></form>

<a class="vote-up-off">up vote</a>

<span class="vote-count-post"><?php echo $row["upvotes"]+$row["downvotes"];?></span>

 <a class="vote-down-off" id="<?php echo mysql_prep($_GET['ques']);?>" >down vote</a>

 <a class="star-off" href="#">favorite</a>
</div>
```

and my jquery code is

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$(".vote-up-off").click(function(){
// here i want the id of form field and votecountpost field which is up and down to this field
})
})
```

the div field repeats again and again as the field present on database.So i want to get the particular field id using jquery and will perform some action using jquery.
How to find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        $("document").ready(function () {
            $('.vote-up-off').live('click', function () {
                var formId = $(this).parents('form').attr('id');
                var voteCountPost = $(this).next('.vote-count-post').attr('id');
            });
        });
```

for form u can add class="VoteForm". so that it take that form attribute id in parents('').

```
        $("document").ready(function () {
            $('.vote-up-off').live('click', function () {
                var formId = $(this).parents('form.VoteForm').attr('id');
                var voteCountPost = $(this).next('.vote-count-post').attr('id');
            });
        });
```

Comment: it works...thanx for the help...is there any another way..excpt parent()..to go up or down..????

Answer (score 1):

Each div needs its own `id`. If the divs are created in a PHP loop, you can do this by incrementing a variable:

```
$divNumber=1;
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($results) )
{
    echo '<div id="fields-'.$divNumber.'">';
    // echo div content here
    echo '</div>';
    ++$divNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this line:

```
$(".vote-up-off).click(function(){...
```

it should be:

```
$(".vote-up-off").click(function(){...
```